# How to split array form in multiple smaller component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I stumbled upon an article explaining array forms in react 
https://goshakkk.name/array-form-inputs/. I was wondering if it was possible to split the component Goshakk wrote into a smaller component. I tried it but had trouble syncing the data from the child to the parent.

```
class IncorporationForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      shareholders: [{ name: '' }],
    };
  }

  // ...

  handleShareholderNameChange = (idx) => (evt) => {
    const newShareholders = this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, sidx) => {
      if (idx !== sidx) return shareholder;
      return { ...shareholder, name: evt.target.value };
    });

    this.setState({ shareholders: newShareholders });
  }

  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    const { name, shareholders } = this.state;
    alert(`Incorporated: ${name} with ${shareholders.length} shareholders`);
  }

  handleAddShareholder = () => {
    this.setState({
      shareholders: this.state.shareholders.concat([{ name: '' }])
    });
  }

  handleRemoveShareholder = (idx) => () => {
    this.setState({
      shareholders: this.state.shareholders.filter((s, sidx) => idx !== sidx)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        {/* ... */}
        <h4>Shareholders</h4>

        {this.state.shareholders.map((shareholder, idx) => (
          <div className="shareholder">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder={`Shareholder #${idx + 1} name`}
              value={shareholder.name}
              onChange={this.handleShareholderNameChange(idx)}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleRemoveShareholder(idx)} className="small">-</button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="button" onClick={this.handleAddShareholder} className="small">Add Shareholder</button>
        <button>Incorporate</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

How would you split this code into components?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do complete iteration of map in one of the component call that in another component which will contain form and then call that component in your current component.

Note: pass required method or data as porps

Comment: I tried to do that but I had trouble syncing the data between the parent and the children when doing a controlled component. ( had no trouble using uncontrolled but needed controlled for my use case)